# How can I extract multiple fieldnames/column values - Codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Suppose I have this native query on my model:

```
public function print_query($id){

$sql = "Select Field1,Field2,Field3.. FROM Table WHERE id = '".$id."' ";

    if($this->db->query($sql, array($id))->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    return $this->db->query($sql, array($id))->result();
    }
}
```

And this on my Controller:

```
public function emp_preview(){

$EmpID =  $this->input->post('txt_id');
$data['p_det'] = $this->db_sal_details->print_query($EmpID);
$this->load->view('employee/preview',$data,TRUE);

}
```

And in my View: I wanted to display the values of Field1,Field2,Field3,and so on.,
I used this code to display them;

```
<table>
<tr>                            
<?php if($p_det):?>
<?php foreach($p_det as $det):?>
<th><?php echo $det->Field1;?></th>
<th><?php echo $det->Field2;?></th>
<th><?php echo $det->Field2;?></th>
...
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is all work fine and display the field and its values. But what if i have more than just 3 fields (50 fields e.g) and I want to dynamically populate the TH with out typing each Fields. How can i do this.,?

I know it's very simple for you experts ,.but I'm just a beginner here.. please bear with me and help me with this one., Thanks in Advance for any replies..

Comment: if($this->db->query($sql, array($id))->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    return $this->db->query($sql, array($id))->result();
    }
you are runnig the query twice here btw

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use foreach to iterate through the property which contains Field1, Field2.etc of the object $det

Comment: I used foreach on my view to iterate and display the values.Do I need some foreach?,Where should i put it and how. Can you show me how please?? Thanks for the reply by the way.,

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public function print_query($id){

$sql = "Select Field1,Field2,Field3.. FROM Table WHERE id = '".$id."' ";

    if($this->db->query($sql, array($id))->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    return $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
    }
}
```

View

```
<table>
<tr>                            
<?php if($p_det):?>
<?php foreach($p_det->result_array() as $det):?>
<?php foreach($det as $field => values){?>
<th><?php echo $columns[$field] = $values;?></th>
...
<?php 
}
endforeach;
?>
<?php endif;?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried this one on my view but it says error to me:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: employee/preview.php

Line Number: 92

Comment: hmm my question, Do you want to show only the field name? or field name+value? In your view its only loop the value of field

Comment: Only the values ., I wanted to show it dynamically without typing each field names., I guess it will be done by a looping but i don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: i just edited the model and view, its all i can help btw its only show the value without specific field.